# Good Reference for Hudson/Maven/Mercurial Integration

Tags: maven, mercurial, hudson, nexus

Can anyone provide a good reference (web, book etc.) that explains how to set up Hudson to do builds/releases using Maven/Nexus and Mercurial?  I would like to set up our system to do Maven builds in Hudson based on updates to our Mercurial SCM projects which are automatically deployed to our local Nexus server.  Some of the project are dependent on others.  I can find quite a few references that refer to one part of the equation, but haven't found anything that details all the pieces together.

TIA!!

**EDIT**

I think what I am looking for initially is more of a general overview of how to use these tools in an integrated manner.  And then I can delve into the details.  What I'm looking for is how to use Hudson to do/verify builds and based on the results, push the artifacts to the appropriate Maven/Nexus repository (snapshot or not) and also possibly deploy applications from Hudson as well to our pre-prod systems.  The fact that I'm using Mercurial is incidental.

Hopefully that clarified and didn't muddy my question...

Comment: Just an FYI, Hudson is now Jenkins... http://jenkins-ci.org/

Comment: No, now there is also Jenkins.  We are using Hudson.

Comment: I know, I just hadn't heard of anyone knowing the difference and actually choosing to go with Hudson.  Why would you want to stay with Hudson?  Is anyone still committing to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the books, I did our integration by using Hudson help.

I think, though, that one area is totally not clear out of the box: providing your own version of `settings.xml` ( that's where you may set custom repository, profiles, etc )

Here are the steps:

1. Go to Hudson->Manage Hudson->Maven 3 Configuration
2. Under 'Documents' tab click 'Add'
3. Change 'Type' drop-down to 'SETTINGS'
4. Give it a meningful name ( e.g. my-custom-settings )
5. Cut and paste the WHOLE xml that you would usually put into $HOME/.m2/settings.xml
6. Hit 'Save' button at the bottom of the screen.

Now you are ready to setup Maven project

1. Create new job and tie it to your source control
2. Add 'Invoke Maven 3' build step
3. Click 'Advanced' button
4. In expanded list find 'Settings' drop down
5. Choose 'my-custom-settings'.

With custom settings you can provide deploy credentials, custom profiles, etc.

I really wish Hudson team would have provided similar instructions in their help for Maven build step, instead of links to 'Settings Reference' at maven.apache.org website.

As for mercurial integration, quick search returned this article -> http://www.ashlux.com/wordpress/2010/06/16/triggering-hudson-builds-with-mercurial-hooks/

I am not mercurial expert, but the article is consistent with the setup we used for our SCM integration.

Comment: Hi, I added a settings.xml file to hudson user's repository since it was needed to access our Nexus repository. But I'm still lost on when/how to push the artifacts to the Nexus repository.

Comment: @sdoca. Add 'deploy' to 'goals' edit box in 'Invoke Maven 3' build step options.  It may be cleaner to add a new build step specifically dedicated to 'deploy'.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog which talks about setting up project using Jenkins and maven, If i am right Jenkins is a spin off from Hudson. Try it out it might help

http://prasannatalakanti.blogspot.com/2011/08/continuous-integration-using-open.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link, but the blog doesn't speak to the issue of deploying artifacts to Nexus.  That's a critical piece of the puzzle I'm looking for.

Comment: Hudson is now Jenkins, long story short, Sun said they owned the name and was being bossy so the community said they'd just rename it Jenkins and keep working on it separate from Sun, and they did.

Comment: @sdoca: There are a couple of specific settings in the project configuration page for Maven projects under Jenkins (fka Hudson). Setting up a toy Jenkins installation will make you realise that it's easier done than read about :-)